# How to Draw Half the Symmetrical Matrix

Tags: matrix

I am dealing with symmetrical matrices in my Thesis,So are there any built in tools to just create Half of the Symmetrical Matrix..As I deal with lot of data,it helps me in saving time.Can any one please suggest me how to draw these Matrix.

[image: Symmetrical Matrix]

[image: Half Matrix]

Comment: Please give some more information. Which application or programming language are you using? Which format does your matrix have? ...

Comment: Hey,I am using Java..Mainly working On Cluster Analysis..I mean its Double Array Matrix.I already done doing my Task with Symmetrical Matrix..But the problem now is..While Documenting my Thesis..I need to  showing the examples of Symmetrical Matrix in the form Half Matrix.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use loops:

```
for(int row=0;row<rowcount;++row)
    for(int col=row;col<colcount;++col)
        print cell
```

Comment: I think u did't Understand wht i am saying...I know if I use loops i can,but i need only half matrix..which means I there any tool or software  to just draw the matrix in word Document..